# how to show image from url in a post by facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

i am programming a Facebook app using graph version 2.5 this app should post in member time line and it works fine but when i add an image URL to post content it appear as link. not like when you paste a URL for image or video that appear as thumbnail in post content 
here is my post.php page

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connection.php");

require_once __DIR__ . '/sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

$getToken=$mysqli->query("select uid,accessToken from users");

while($token=mysqli_fetch_array($getToken)){
   echo $token['accessToken'];
   echo "<br>".$token['uid'];
   try {
         $params = array(

          "message" => "this is a test for adding post wiht image URL using facebook Application http://mcq-tests.com/athcar/images/cartoon.jpg ",
       "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
       "caption" => "www.meem-tech.com",
       "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using  Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

 $ret=$fb->post('/'.$token['uid'].'/feed',$params,$token['accessToken']);
     echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
     } catch(Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}

}


?>
```

this is what i got if i publish a post using the Facebook application

[image]

and this is what i got if I paste the image URL manually in my Facebook timeline
[image]

so my question is how to make my app show the image or video as the same way if i do it manually

Comment: You need to post a `link`. How this usually works, is that people post a link to an actual HTML document, and set the image as the thumbnail for that link. If you use the image URL directly as the `link` value, then you might still not get the desired result.

Comment: but in facebook if I copy and paste the image URL it works normally so how i can do the same form the app could you please show me an example 
thanks

Comment: _"but in facebook"_ - sorry, Invalid Argument Error. UI and API are two different and separate things. // A lot of simple examples can be found in the documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/